# Specifying the font size and font style for plot legends

Tags: plotting, legending

How can I change the font size and font style for the line legends?

```
 Plot[{xe, xi}, {y, 1, 10}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, (FontSize -> 16)], 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"xe", "xi"}], {0.85, 0.85}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Dashed]}]
```

Comment: Use `Style[#, "Arial", Blue, 20,Italic] & /@ {"xe", "xi"}` for common settings, or `Style["xe","TR",Black,12]` for individual legend.

Comment: where is the place of Style? when i put it inside the linelegend i don't get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.

```
Plot[{xe, xi}, {y, 1, 10}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, (FontSize -> 16)], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[
    Style[#, "Arial", Blue, 20] & /@ {"xe", "xi"}], {0.85, 0.85}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Dashed]}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{xe, xi}, {y, 1, 10}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, (FontSize -> 16)], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Style["xe", "TR", Blue, 20], 
     Style["xi", Red, "Arial", 16, Italic]}], {0.85, 0.85}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Dashed]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help dear @Alx